# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jssc.SerialNativeInterface.getSerialPortNames()

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm doing a processing based project with eclipse and Procliping. When I'm testing the project with "Run" command inside the IDE, everything works fine. But if I export it into a runable-jar, when I run the jar it'll give this error on the line `String[] li=Serial.list();`. Any idea what's going wrong?

Java source attachment is "processing-2.2.1/modes/java/libraries/serial/src"

And here is a sample code:

```
package abcd;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.serial.Serial;

public class TestUI extends PApplet {
    Serial port;

    public void setup(){
        System.out.println(Serial.list());
    }
    public void draw(){
    }
    public static void main(String _args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { abcd.TestUI.class.getName() });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample to reproduce this problem?

Comment: It seems that you are using a JNI library. You need to make sure you can load the DLL files after package them into a JAR file.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work? I can hardly figure out why it runs differently after I export the project

Comment: Please post the exported JAR file and complete exception trace. Besides, please list all external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

My approach of solving it:

Download the latest version of [java-simple-serial-connector](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/)(Which is the base library used for Processing's serial library), replace jssc.jar in the lib folder, and the error will be gone, and my application runs smoothly.

However the base library is 4 times bigger than the modified version used in Processing, so there may be some unnecessary features involved.

Seems like in their latest alpha version, Processing [solved the same problem for exporting apps](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2559)(at least in windows) by adding more look-up paths, while keeping their Serial library intact. I'm not familiar with their development environment, so I didn't look further into it. There may be a simpler solution.